# ATK Examples directing to a different DSN

Tags: atk4

Just installed atk4 (latest) on my webserver.

The default page loads fine, the DB test shows success, but the examples included in the package seem to be referencing a dsn other than what is in the config. Despite my (working) config info the examples try to connect to root@localhost and fail. That's not my dsn info from config.

I checked the agiletoolkit site and their example.agiletookit page is doing the same thing.

Is this a bug or are there multiple configs?

Comment: Issue also reported here by you: https://github.com/atk4/atk4/issues/263

Comment: ChadM you found the reason why this was happening, so I guess you can answer your own question here to get some points :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed using the new secure install

```
curl -sS http://agiletoolkit.org/install | sh
```

Then there was a problem with the bootstrapped repository. Here is fix:

https://github.com/atk4/atk4-secure/commit/a0c282e35277a044ed9048b7c292ac8da1b3092a